# How to form a Solr edismax query with mutiple fields and different minimum match and boosts for different fields?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I've a Solr index with all documents having three fields - name, address and other_addresses. I want to search for a person having name say 'Tom Cruise' and Address '3rd Avenue 23rd Floor New York, NY 10016'.

Now I want to search name in only name field having its some specific boost value and minimum match value as well. Also, address need to be searched in both address and other_addresses, with different mm and boost values.

Can someone help me in writing edismax query on any other way around for Solr?

I'm doing something like :

`select?debugQuery=on&defType=edismax&fl=*%20score&mm=70%25&q=name%3A(Rita%20Suman%20Shinde%20Near)%20address%3A(Gunjan%20Talkies%20Yerwada%20Pune)%20other_addresses%3A(Gunjan%20Talkies%20Yerwada%20Pune)&qf=name%20other_addresses%20address&stopwords=true`

but not able to figure how to give different mm values.

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I've gone through the documentation, but not able to figure out how to have mm different for different fields.

Comment: Please mention what all been tried from your end in the question and how?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LocalParams to compose several dismax queries into one, and each of those subqueries can have its own dismax parameters. For example:

```
q={!dismax qf=name mm=2 v=$q1}^2.0 {!dismax qf=address1 mm=4 v=$q2}^1.5 {!dismax qf=other_address mm=4 v=$q2}^1.0
q1=Tom Cruise
q2=3rd Avenue 23rd Floor New York, NY 10016
```